# How to static_assert that an initializer list is a certain size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

Would it be possible to verify that an initializer list that is being passed to a `constexpr` constructor is a certain size?  Or would this only be possible to do at runtime?

This is the idea, but it doesn't work:

```
struct group
{
        constexpr group(
            std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<UINT const> const> groups
        )
        {
            static_assert(each_list_size_greater_than_1(groups.begin(), groups.end()));
        }

        constexpr static bool each_list_size_greater_than_1(
            std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<UINT const> const>::const_iterator const begin
            , std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<UINT const> const>::const_iterator const end)
        {
            return begin == end || begin->size() > 1 && each_list_size_greater_than_1(begin + 1, end);
        }
};
```

I've looked at VS2015's `std::initializer_list` implementation and `begin()`, `end()` and `size()` are all `constexpr` functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the `size()` of an `std::initializer_list<T>` can evaluate to a `constexpr` the `size()` member won't behave like a `constexpr` within a `constexpr` function: it is intentional that objects only behave like `constexpr` within the `constexpr` expression where they were introduce but not elsewhere.

For example:

```
constexpr get_size(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
    constexpr std::size_t csize = list.size(); // ERROR (1)
    std::size_t           size  = list.size(); // OK
    return size;
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t csize = get_size(std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }); // OK (2)
    // ...
}
```

In the first case (1) the value which is assumed to yield a `constexpr` depends on data created before the `constexpr` starts. As a result, it doesn't evaluate to a `constexpr`. In the second case (2) the data is defined within the `constexpr` and, thus, the result can become a `constexpr`.

I haven't been part of the discussions leading to this design but it seems it is motivated by the desire to prevent `constexpr` arguments changing the result type of a `constexpr` function: if the values were `constexpr`s within the function definition, they would also be `constexpr`s in the return value and could, thus, be used as template arguments in the return type. That would lead to different values to `constexpr` function yielding different types. So far, you can get a different return type only by varying the argument types of a function and/or by changing the number of arguments of a function.

Comment: What is meant by your last statement: `So far, you can get a different return type only be varying the template arguments and/or their number.`?

Comment: @Adrian: according to the C++ standards at least up to C++1z you cannot create different return types for a function based on the _value_ of the function arguments. You'll need to change the _type_ of the function to change its return type. I do realize you aren't interested in actually changing the return type of a function but rather just use an argument value as a `constexpr`. However, if an argument value can be used as a `constexpr` within a function the same value could be used in the return type, thereby making something possible which is currently not allowed.